# Unable to Capture Screen shot In AndEngine

Tags: android, screenshot, andengine

HI here is my Code.

```
public static void TakeScreenShot(String FileName)
{ 
         Log.d("Screen"," Path "+ FileName);

        scr.capture(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, FileName, new IScreenCaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScreenCaptured(final String pFilePath) { 
                Log.d("Screen","Yes "+ pFilePath);

            }

            @Override
            public void onScreenCaptureFailed(final String pFilePath, final Exception pException) { 
                Log.d("Screen","NO "+ pFilePath+"    "+pException);

            }
        });
    }
```

The first log is working fine. But then no other log is working.
Its not completing nor its failing.
Can any one give me a solution?

The path where I am saving is
    "/mnt/sdcard/cmtdd.png"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The follwing might work..I have added scene.attachChild(screenCapture); to your code. It should used at the correct place.

```
public static void TakeScreenShot(String FileName)
{ 
         Log.d("Screen"," Path "+ FileName);

        scene.attachChild(screenCapture); // Attaching screen capture after all rendered.

        scr.capture(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, FileName, new IScreenCaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScreenCaptured(final String pFilePath) { 
                Log.d("Screen","Yes "+ pFilePath);

            }

            @Override
            public void onScreenCaptureFailed(final String pFilePath, final Exception pException) { 
                Log.d("Screen","NO "+ pFilePath+"    "+pException);

            }
        });
    }
```